# Pass vector of char vectors to char**

Tags: c++, vector, stl, char

Is it possible to pass a `std::vector<std::vector<char>>` to a function `void doSomething(char** arr)` e.g. to store a bunch of paths

similar as with

`std::vector<char> vec` to `void func(char *str)`

```
vec.assign(64, ' ');
```

Function call: `func(vec.data());`

Comment: No only if you convert the vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly, as the vector of vectors does not store an array to its children data adresses. So you have to build this array

```
std::vector<char*> temp(vec.size);
for(unsigned int i=0;i<vec.size();i++) {
    temp[i] = vec[i].data();
}

doSomething(temp.data());
```

Answer (score 0):

Full example:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> vec(16, std::vector<char>(255));
std::vector<char*> temp(vec.size());
for(unsigned int i=0;i<vec.size();i++) 
{
    temp[i] = vec[i].data();
}

doSomething(temp.data());
```

Thx galinette!